# Fork example output

Tags: c

Can anyone explain why this piece of code prints `n=3` and not `n=4`?

```
int main() {
    int n = 1;
    if (fork() == 0) {
        n = n + 1;
        exit(0);
    }
    n = n + 2;
    printf("%d: %d\n", getpid(), n);
    wait(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why should it print `n = 4`?

Comment: Can anyone explain why it should print `4`?

Comment: `n` increases by `1` in the child process

Comment: to start, the posted code is missing the necessary header files for wait(), getpid(), exit(), fork()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `fork` the child process gets a copy of the address space that is not shared with the parent.  In your example the child process increments `n` by 1 and then exits.  The parent, which still has the original `n` equal to 1 increments it by 2 to 3 and then prints.  Note that it should be added while [copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) can be used to map the same physical memory to two different virtual memory address spaces when you modify (write) one virtual page each process will get its own copy, hence the name copy on write.

For the visual people:

Before you call fork you one have process that has a memory space like this:

```
#############
## n == 1 ### Stack
#############
#############
############# Rest of memory, heap/text/data/bss
#############
```

After the fork two process with basically identical virtual memory space:

```
   Parent                              Child
#############                      #############
## n == 1 ### Stack                ## n == 1 ### Stack
#############                      #############
#############                      #############
############# Rest of memory,      ############# Rest of memory,
############# heap/text/data/bss   ############# heap/text/data/bss
#############                      #############
```

Lets say the child runs first (it doesn't have to the parent could run first but the result doesn't change).  The child will increment `n` and you will get this:

```
   Parent                              Child
#############                      #############
## n == 1 ### Stack                ## n == 2 ### Stack
#############                      #############
#############                      #############
############# Rest of memory,      ############# Rest of memory,
############# heap/text/data/bss   ############# heap/text/data/bss
#############                      #############
```

Note that the parent's value of `n` has not changed.  The child then exits and it's virtual address space is destroyed.

```
   Parent
#############
## n == 1 ### Stack
#############
#############
############# Rest of memory,
############# heap/text/data/bss
#############
```

The parent then increments `n` by 2 and prints the value of `n`

```
   Parent
#############
## n == 3 ### Stack
#############
#############
############# Rest of memory,
############# heap/text/data/bss
#############
```

Hence why you get 3 instead of 4.

Comment: @iharob `fork` does not share the address space, `vfork` does but in the example code he is using `fork`

Comment: Yes you are right, I just freaked out when I saw both having the same _virtual_ addresses, which is why they are the same, because they're virtual.

Answer (score 1):

The new process doesn't share memory with the previous process, it's created with a copy of it, so the `n` you modify inside the new process is not the same of the old process.

Even if they shared memory, your code wouldn't necessarily print `4` because you wait for the child process to finish after printing the value in the parent process.

Answer (score 0):

a fork'd child process gets a copy of the data, not the actual data.

The code 'assumes' that the fork() was successful.
That is not a 'robust' assumption.
Always check, after a fork(), for a error condition (for fork() that would be a -1 indicates an error occurred.

Since there is no check for the error condition, the code after the 'if' block might be in an error path or in a parent path.